# Can you create the table field with TEXT datatype

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have checked this tutorial [Create table in MySql](https://www.developerhelps.com/mysql-create-database/). But how to add the new field with TEXT datatype. Can you provide the solution for that.

```
CREATE TABLE MyFirst_Table (  
   MyFirst_Table_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
   MyFirst_Table_firstname VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,  
   MyFirst_Table_surname VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
   MyFirst_Table_fname VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,  
   PRIMARY KEY ( MyFirst_Table_id )  
);
```

I want the table creation with TEXT datatype for string type field.

Comment: Is there an error? If so, can you add it to your question?

Comment: You only appear to be using `INT` and `VARCHAR` types. Where did you want to use [`TEXT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html)?

Comment: Give me the solution for adding new field with TEXT datatype.

Comment: People are confused and asking you questions because what you want to do is something that should be clear how to do: just use the `TEXT` type. Since it appears obvious as to what to do, people are assuming that you already tried to do it, but experienced problems when you tried. Thus, they want to know what you actually tried and what the errors/problems you experienced when you, supposedly, tried to do it. If you just didn't try anything, then saying that would probably clear up the confusion.

Comment: ... Please_Do_Not_Prefix_Columns. Otherwise_You_Will_Have_Long_Column_Name_If_You_Create_Intersection_Tables_...._id

Answer (score 1):

try using just `TEXT` eg for column  `MyFirst_Table_fname`

```
CREATE TABLE MyFirst_Table (  
   MyFirst_Table_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
   MyFirst_Table_firstname VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,  
   MyFirst_Table_surname VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
   MyFirst_Table_fname TEXT,  
   PRIMARY KEY ( MyFirst_Table_id )  
);
```

varchar need  a string  length  max spec up to 256 char ..  TEXT is a string data type that can store up to 65,535 characters

Comment: ```MySQL VARCHAR is the variable-length string whose length can be up to 65,535 -- MySQL stores a VARCHAR value as a 1-byte or 2-byte length prefix plus actual data.```

Comment: ```The TEXT is useful for storing long-form text strings that can take from 1 byte to 4 GB```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address text
);
```

Reference : http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-text/

Comment: don't forget ```PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT```